# onload Fancybox: trying to add link to target="_blank" page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Got the onLoad Fancybox to work just fine... but I want to redirect OR open a _blank page when clicking on the image or close button.

Here is what I got so far... at http://cumberlandhorizons.com/box-test3.html

Want the link to go HERE... http://cumberlandhorizons.com/box-end.html

Here is my code for the box-test.html page...

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> - Fancybox Test 03</title>  
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>    
      <script type='text/javascript' src="source/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>    
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="source/jquery.fancybox.css">  

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(function(){
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$("#hidden_link").fancybox({
    onComplete: function () {
        $("#fancybox-img").wrap($("<a http://cumberlandhorizons.com/>", {
            href: this.href, //or your target link
            target: "_blank"
        }));
    }
}).trigger("click");
});//]]>  
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a id="hidden_link" href=" http://cumberlandhorizons.com/img/00subs.jpg"    style="visibility:hidden;"></a>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems worth mentioning that you're not supposed to link to the source files on the fancyapps site.

Comment: my bad,,, I know better.  Fixed.